# How to install "Vue Select" to my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webpack, vue.js, asset-pipeline

I use Vue.js in my Rails application using gem named [vuejs-rails](https://github.com/adambutler/vuejs-rails), and now I want to use js plugin named [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select)

they say using npm to install and write the below code to my js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
```

But it didn't work.

I have two questions.

First one is "How to introduce vue-select plugin to my Rails app (using asset pipeline)

Second one is "Why Asset Pipeline replaced by Webpack in Rails5?" I heard that by using webpack, it's much easier to use js and js plugins in Rails. But I couldn't get why asset pipeline is bad and webpack is good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

It seems that [vuejs-rails](https://github.com/adambutler/vuejs-rails) doesn't have `vue-select` component. At least, it is not mentioned there. It is probably due to the fact that it's not a part of `Vue.js` but is rather a custom component. However, you might want to try using [sprockets-vue](https://github.com/kikyous/sprockets-vue) that allows converting `.vue` files into `js` objects.

As for the second question, Webpack doesn't replace Asset Pipeline in Rails 5. It is not even there. Instead, it will be included in Rails 5.1 together with Yarn, and they will coexist with Asset Pipeline ([reference](https://github.com/rails/webpacker)).